# How to get React to work with Grunt and Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gruntjs, babeljs

I am trying to integrate React into a current project utilizing Grunt build which we currently have.

I have gone to *grunt-react* https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-react, which says it has been deprecated and that I should use *grunt-babel*. https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel

Does this just work out of the box with compiling React? Do I need to install anything else like *babel-preset-react* https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/ in order to get this to work?

Also, I'm not sure how I set up my Gruntfile to handle this, currently I have:

```
    babel: {
        options {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['es2015']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/',
                    src: ['*.js'],
                    dest: 'dist/'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope you got your solution still answering here, it will help some people who needs to work react with grunt and babel

make sure first you have installed the followings:

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-babel babel-cli
```

Grunt plugin for Babel [grunt-babel](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel)

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd 

npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev 

npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-react
```

then add a grunt task/gruntfile as below :

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
'use strict';
  grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            presets: ["env", "react"],
            plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './src',
                src: ['*.js'],
                dest: './generated',
                ext: '.js'
            }]
        }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel']);
};
```

package.json

```
   "devDependencies": {
       "babel-cli": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
       "babel-core": "7.0.0-alpha.19",
       "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^7.0.0-alpha.19",
       "babel-preset-env": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
       "babel-preset-es2015": "7.0.0-alpha.19",
       "babel-preset-react": "^7.0.0-alpha.19",
       "grunt-babel": "^7.0.0",
 }
```

Hope this helps.

**EDITED**

**babel -> @babel**

> Since Babel 7 the Babel team switched to scoped packages, so you now  have to use @babel/core instead of babel-core.
>
> Your dependencies will need to be modified like so:
>
> babel-cli -> @babel/cli. Ex:  babel- with @babel/.

package.json will be look like below:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
"@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"grunt-babel": "^8.0.0",
```